# Using Chrome NPAPI plugins

Tags: google-chrome, npapi

How do I use NPAPI plugins in Chrome? I know they are old, etc. But many plugins are still NPAPI plugins, and I would like to install them.

Comment: The answer is: Not possible (as Serge mentioned on the answer below). Use a different browser. Or somehow use plugins that is using PPAPI (which is supported by Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You have to reconsider the browser then:

> To make browsing with Chrome safer, faster, and more stable, we stopped allowing NPAPI plugins on September 1, 2015.

[Source](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en)